# How to apply check on '0'?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am creating a query where I am supposed to add column values and values is in one column at a time. Now I am using `ISNULL(Col1,Col2)` to check if any column contains value. Now suddenly there is some sort of change in the code and now instead of going `NULL` in the database column it is saving 0 so ISNULL is not working on those columns and picking up the `Col1` which is in the first place I suppose.

Is there anyway to handle this without rewriting the entire query or digging up more ?

Here is my query if anyone wants to look at.

```
;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT 
ID, SUM(DrAmount) [DrAmount], SUM(CrAmount) [CrAmount]
FROM FICO.tbl_TransactionDetail
GROUP BY ID
)
SELECT ID, D.DrAmount, D.CrAmount, D.Amount, D.Amount-ISNULL(D.DrAmount,D.CrAmount) [Opening]
    FROM(
        SELECT *,
                SUM(ISNULL(DrAmount, 0)+ISNULL(CrAmount, 0)) OVER (ORDER BY ID 
                         ) as Amount
        FROM CTE
        )D
```

Comment: In your code, it won't matter if the amounts are `0`.  The code should just work.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I don't know but somehow it's not.

Comment: `ISNULL(NULLIF(col1, 0), col2)` - Is that you are looking?

Comment: @BhatiaAshish That worked perfectly. Gracias

Comment: Will all the values of *`NULL`* be changed to `0`? if so, why not use a `CASE` expression? `CASE col1 WHEN 0 THEN col2 ELSE col1 END`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per comments, I have use `ISNULL(NULLIF(col1, 0), col2)` trick for this issue. Here is updated query -

```
;WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT 
    ID,
    SUM(DrAmount) [DrAmount],
    SUM(CrAmount) [CrAmount]
  FROM FICO.tbl_TransactionDetail
  GROUP BY ID
)
SELECT
  ID,
  D.DrAmount,
  D.CrAmount,
  D.Amount,
  D.Amount-ISNULL(D.DrAmount,D.CrAmount) [Opening]
FROM(
        SELECT
          *,
          SUM(ISNULL(NULLIF(DrAmount, 0), 0)+ISNULL(NULLIF(CrAmount, 0), 0)) OVER (ORDER BY ID) as Amount
        FROM CTE
    )D
```